# Add hold functionality to Windows Mouse Keys

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, mouse, accessibility

I'm using Windows 8.1 which has a very useful built-in tool called Mouse Keys (which can be accessed from `Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Center\Make the mouse easier to use`). It's very useful when too many clicks strains your hand.

A similar tool exists in Ubuntu, which also allows holding the `5` key to emulate holding down the selected mouse button. In Windows version, the only way is to use the `0` (MB down) and `,` (MB up). Needless to say, holding `5` is way easier.

Is there any way I can add this to the Windows version? Alternative programs that does this is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows operating system only provided the options to move mouse pointer via dedicated numbers as well as the other buttons to click or drag items.

Reference:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14204/windows-7-use-mouse-keys-to-move-mouse-pointer

Comment: Thank you. Looks like they did not give any option to modify it. I would appreciate other answers to provide any means possible to do this. (I can't +1 you until I have 15 reputation, I will wait for a few days for more possible answers before accepting your answer)